# How to decode the EWS folder sync state?

Tags: exchangewebservices

MSDN article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa565970(v=exchg.150).aspx says that the sync state is a base64 encoded string. But I was never able to decode it straight away.

Is there a way to decode it?

Answer (score 1):

While it is base64-encoded, you cannot decode it into anything meaningful. It's intended to be an opaque value to the client.